# Show canvas image on all id

Tags: javascript

I have an image URL and I want to show it on 2 canvas

```js
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("scream");
    
function draw() {
   ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
}
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" onload="draw()" src="http://i.imgur.com/S1juY4A.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: Element IDs must be unique throughout the html document.

Comment: i want to show on all class @ANON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Id must be unique, but name can be equal.
2. If you using canvas inside
   function onload, you not need to find image element in the dom.
3. Also i have upgraded your code, now it works with simple resize.
4. Draw function will be more universal, if we make a canvas dom selector as function input param.

```js
    
    function draw(img, canvasSelector) {
        var canvases = document.querySelectorAll(canvasSelector);
        for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
          var canvas = canvases[i];
          var factor = Math.min(canvas.height/img.height,  canvas.width/img.width);
          canvas.width = Math.round(img.width* factor);
          canvas.height = Math.round(img.height* factor);
          canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        }
    }
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" onload="draw(this,'canvas[name=myCanvas]')" src="http://i.imgur.com/S1juY4A.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas name="myCanvas" width="125" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas name="myCanvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `ID` must be unique in a document.

Give different `IDs` to the canvas elements to select them. If you have many canvas elements having similar `class`, you can use `for-loop` or `Array#forEach` loop to achieve the same. Use `document.querySelectorAll` to select elements.

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("scream");

function draw() {
  ctx1.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  ctx2.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" onload="draw()" src="http://i.imgur.com/S1juY4A.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

**For all the canvas elements having similar `class`**

```js
var img = document.getElementById("scream");

function draw() {
  var cElems = document.querySelectorAll('.canvasClass');
  [].forEach.call(cElems, function(elem) {
    var ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  });
}
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" onload="draw()" src="http://i.imgur.com/S1juY4A.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" class="canvasClass" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" class="canvasClass" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```